# NGINX Rewrite Redirection Issu

Tags: nginx

I have an NGINX setup, trying to rewrite a URL from /system to /fs, I have this code:

```
location /system {
    rewrite ^ /fs last;
}
```

For some reason it just redirects to a folder called /fs and I get a not found.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
location /system {
    alias /path/to/fs;
}
```

http://nginx.org/r/alias

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite Rule is not correct.

**^** is the beginning of a rewrite string this make no sense.

try something like this:

```
rewrite ^system(.*)$ /fs$1 permanent;
```

Here is a short [Tutorial](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html).
New [Tutorial](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/useful-rewrites-for-nginx/)

**Edit:** I think you should write your rewrite rule under your server block and i have changed the rule.

Comment: This didn't work, I now get a 'File not found' on both /fs and system.